# Pass value from child to parent without onChange react

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using a component to do the Input of Select called SelectInput.

Here is my code:

```
'use strict'
import React from 'react'

class SelectInput extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            select: "",
            items: []
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)    
    }

    .
    .
    .

    handleChange(event){
        console.log(event.target.value)
        this.setState({
            select: event.target.value
        });
        if(this.props.onChange) {
            this.props.onChange(event)
        }
    }

    render(){
        let disabled = this.state.items.length > 1 ? false : true,
            selected = this.state.items ? this.state.items[0] : ""
        return (
            <select name={this.props.name} disabled={disabled} defaultValue={selected} value={this.state.select} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                {this.state.items && this.state.items.map(item =>
                    <option value={item} >{item}</option>
                )}

            </select>
        )
    }
}
```

My problem is when my select has only one option, I disable the select and insert the value as default. But I dont get the value of event at onChange to pass to the parent component.

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you disable element? why you except a change event? and why you disable the element? why the user will interact with a disabled element?

Comment: I disable the element because the component has only one client, and this components knows this client. I have a list of countries either, but at this moment I have only one country. So why I will enable the select? And if I have two or more elements and set the default value to the first element of the list, how can I pass this element to the parent component if I did not change the select?

Comment: in that case you can call the `handleChange()` while rendering itself if no of items is 1. Because user is no way can interact with the element.

Comment: I did not understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that if you want call the`handleChange` method even with one item is to having a state up-to-date or/and calling the handler `onChange` passed by props.

At some point your `state.items` must be populated :

```
componentWillMount(){
  // load data (ajax or hard-coded)
  let items = ['toto'];
  let select = items.length ? items[0] : '';
  this.setState({
    items,
    select
  });
  if(this.props.onChange) {
    this.props.onChange(select);
  }
}
```

I removed the `selected` variable and the `defaultValue` attribute in the `render` method :

```
render(){
    let disabled = this.state.items.length > 1 ? false : true;

    return (
      <select name={this.props.name} disabled={disabled} value={this.state.select} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        {this.state.items && this.state.items.map((item, i) =>
          <option key={i} value={item} >{item}</option>
        )}
      </select>
    )
}
```

Comment: Great point ;) It was something like this that I was looking for